# Which countries in EU guarantee paid lunch break?

Tags: germany, eu, working, poland

In Poland full time employees have a 15 minutes lunch break that counts as paid work time. Employee can start work at 8 am at leave at 4 pm.
In Germany employees have to take a 30 minutes lunch break that doesn't count as work time. If employees start at 8 am they have to stay at least until 4:30 pm.

Which countries in EU guarantee employees paid lunch break (like Poland)? What's the duration of those breaks?

Comment: This question seems on the fence for being too broad to me, as it involves enumerating 28 EU states.

Comment: In the [UK](https://www.gov.uk/rest-breaks-work) in general, workers are entitled for an uninterrupted 20 min break (tea/lunch/whatsoever you call them) if they work 6+ hours, but it is not mandatory to be paid.

Comment: In Germany, there is also a similar right. Insisting on it being paid is silly, though, as the same effect is reached by having a higher hourly rate for the work time. Also, a large number of people get monthly salaries, so which hours are paid and which not doesn't really matter.

Comment: "Employee can start work at 8 am at leave at 4 pm" - only if their contract stipulates a 40 hour working week.  Given I have had full-time contracts varying between 35 hours and 40 hours in the UK (and 42 hours in Switzerland) - all with a 1 hour unpaid lunch break - asking whether lunch break is "paid" or "unpaid" is not really relevant (just be sure you are comparing like-for-like).